# MySQL table replication on the same server

Tags: mysql, replication

I have one the same server (Linux) two databases: db1 and db2 and I want to replicate db1.table1 to db2.table1

I added the following lines to my.cnf and restarted mysql service

```
replicate-do-table = db2.table
replicate-rewrite-db  = database1->database2
```

but it's not working. Are those commands correct ? Do I need to set permissions on both databases ?

mysql version: 5.5.25a

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on why you want to do this, there may be  (different) way... what issue are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Replication was designed to replicate data between two MySQL Instances, not two MySQL Databases within the same instance.

What you need to do is write triggers in db1.table1 to write the same changes to db2.table1.

See my old post [How to set up triggers in MySQL for copying a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/how-to-set-up-triggers-in-mysql-for-copying-a-field/9680#9680) for some ideas.